# Cross-thread operation not valid using async/await in VSTO

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, vsto

I am getting a

> Cross-thread operation not valid

... error with the code below. I thought async/await would take care this, but apparently not. Weird thing is that when I comment out `textBoxUser.Enabled = false`, the error disappears. Thoughts?

```
private async void buttonPopulate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     textBoxUser.Enabled = false;

     await Populate(); 

     textBoxUser.Enabled = true; //error here
}
```

Comment: You are trying to access an GUI element from a different thread.  You need an invoke.

Comment: `private async void buttonPopulate_Click` If WinForms is calling this event handler you should be on the WinForms synchronisation context and continue on the main thread. Are you calling this method yourself or from a timer or actually calling `await Populate().ConfigureAwait(false);`?

Comment: @MongZhu Slightly different problem and the top answers there are out of date

Comment: 1-Post the code for Populate as there may lie the problem.
2-Post the line where you get the exception.

Comment: What's `Populate` doing? Can you repro that with [a simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @paulo, I've already gutted out Populate to just an empty await Task.Run(). I think Stephen's response below is onto something though

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is probably due to VSTO not properly providing a `SynchronizationContext`; this is a long-standing problem with Office plugin systems. You can verify this by checking the value of `SynchronizationContext.Current` at the beginning of your event handler; if it is `null`, then the problem is due to VSTO.

To fix this, you can do this at the beginning of any `async void` event handlers:

```
SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext());
```